# How to see print() results in Tarantool Docker container

Tags: tarantool

I am using `tarantool/tarantool:2.6.0` Docker image (the latest at the moment) and writing lua scripts for the project. I try to find out how to see the results of callin' `print()` function. It's quite difficult to debug my code without print() working.
In tarantool console print() have no effect also.

**Using simple print()**

Docs says that print() works to `stdout`, but I don't see any results when I watch container's logs by `docker logs -f <CONTAINER_NAME>`

I also tried to set container's logs driver to `local`. Than I get one time print to container's logs, but only once...

The container's `/var/log` directory is always empty.

**Using box.session.push()**

Using `box.session.push()` works fine in console, but when I use it in lua script:

```
-- app.lua
function log(s)
  box.session.push(s)
end

-- No effect
log('hello')

function say_something(s)
    log(s)
end

box.schema.func.create('say_something')
box.schema.user.grant('guest', 'execute', 'function', 'say_something')
```

And then call `say_something()` from nodeJs connector like this:

```
const TarantoolConnection = require('tarantool-driver');

const conn = new TarantoolConnection(connectionData);
const res = await conn.call('update_links', 'hello');
```

I get error:
[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you've missed `io.flush()` after `print` command.

After I added `io.flush()` after each `print` call my messages start to write to logs (`docker logs -f <CONTAINER_NAME>`).

Also I'd recommend to use `log` module for such purpose. It writes to stderr without buffering.

Regarding the error in the connector, I think nodejs connector simply doesn't support pushes.